# Android RemoteServiceExeption: Context.startForegroundService() did not then call Service.startForeground()

Tags: android, kotlin, service, android-notifications, crashlytics

I know, there are already many questions about this error. But I tried many solutions and nothing worked for me. I have a Notification Service in my application with a timer in it and crashlytics reports hundreds of crashes (android 8 - 12) like this:

ForegroundServiceDidNotStartInTimeException:

```
Fatal Exception: android.app.ForegroundServiceDidNotStartInTimeException
Context.startForegroundService() did not then call Service.startForeground(): ServiceRecord{cac9d0b u0 com.malmatech.eggtimer/.NotificationUtil}

android.app.ActivityThread.throwRemoteServiceException (ActivityThread.java:2134)
android.app.ActivityThread.access$2900 (ActivityThread.java:309)
android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:2363)
android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:106)
android.os.Looper.loopOnce (Looper.java:226)
android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:313)
android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:8582)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java)
com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (RuntimeInit.java:563)
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:1133)
```

and RemoteServiceException:

```
Fatal Exception: android.app.RemoteServiceException
Context.startForegroundService() did not then call Service.startForeground(): ServiceRecord{d760a21 u0 com.malmatech.eggtimer/.NotificationUtil}

android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:2313)
android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:107)
android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:213)
android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:8178)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java)
com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (RuntimeInit.java:513)
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:1101)
```

I double checked my code and searched the web but didn't find anything and never get these exceptions on my own devices or emulators...

---

The Notification is only shown, when a timer is running and the application is closed. In the onPause() of my TimerActivity I start the service:

```
if (timerState == TimerState.Running){
    timer.cancel()
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        MyContext.getContext().startForegroundService(Intent(this, NotificationUtil::class.java))
    } else {
        startService(Intent(this, NotificationUtil::class.java))
    }
}
```

In onResume() I stop the service:

```
try {
    MyContext.getContext().stopService(
        Intent(
            MyContext.getContext(),
            NotificationUtil::class.java
        )
    )
} catch (ex: Exception) {
    ex.printStackTrace()
}
```

And here is my service class, I cut out some irrelevant code but everything for managing the notification should be included.

```
class NotificationUtil : Service() {
override fun onBind(intent: Intent?): IBinder? {
    return null
}

var eggCount = 1
private var secondsRemaining: Long = 0
private lateinit var timer: CountDownTimer
// some more, irrelevant for question

override fun onStartCommand(intent: Intent?, flags: Int, startId: Int): Int {
    showNotification()
    log("onStartCommand executed with startId: $startId")
    if (intent != null) {
        val action = intent.action
        log("using an intent with action $action")
    } else {
        log("with a null intent. It has been probably restarted by the system.")
    }
    // by returning this we make sure the service is restarted if the system kills the service
    return START_STICKY
}

override fun onCreate() {
    super.onCreate()

    //irrelevant Code - getting an array from SharedPreferences and setting up textToSpeech

    showNotification()
    startTimer()
}

override fun onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy()
    hideNotification()
    timer.cancel()
}

fun showNotification(done: Boolean = false) {
    val nBuilder = NotificationCompat.Builder(applicationContext, "menu_timer")
        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_notification_res_specific)
        .setOngoing(true)
        .setAutoCancel(true)
        .setDefaults(0)
        .setContentIntent(
            getPendingIntentWithStack(
                applicationContext,
                TimerActivity::class.java
            )
        )
        .setPriority(PRIORITY_MAX)
        .setVisibility(VISIBILITY_PUBLIC)
        .setNotificationSilent()

    if (!done) {

        //irrelecantCode, setting ginishedStr and finishedIndividualString

        nBuilder.setContentTitle(getString(R.string.eggTimerRunning))
        if (eggCount > 1) {
            nBuilder.setStyle(
                NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText(
                    getString(R.string.remainingTimeNotification) + " $finishedStr\n" + getString(
                        R.string.nextEggNotification
                    ) + " $finishedIndividualString"
                )
            )
                .setContentText(
                    getString(R.string.remainingTimeNotification) + " $finishedStr\n" + getString(
                        R.string.nextEggNotification
                    ) + " $finishedIndividualString"
                )
        } else {
            nBuilder.setStyle(
                NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle()
                    .bigText(getString(R.string.remainingTimeNotification) + " $finishedStr")
            )
                .setContentText(getString(R.string.remainingTimeNotification) + " $finishedStr")
        }
    } else {
        nBuilder.setContentTitle(getString(R.string.eggTimerDone))
            .setStyle(
                NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText(getString(R.string.BonAppetite))
            )
            .setContentText(getString(R.string.BonAppetite))
    }

    //irrelevant code

    val nManager =
        applicationContext.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager
    nManager.createNotificationChannel("menu_timer", "Timer App Timer", true)

    nManager.notify(135678, nBuilder.build())

    val notification: Notification = nBuilder.build()
    startForeground(135678, notification)
}


private fun hideNotification() {
    val nManager =
        applicationContext.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager
    nManager.cancel(135678)
}

private fun startTimer() {
    timer = object : CountDownTimer(secondsRemaining * 1000, 1000) {
        override fun onFinish() = onTimerFinished()

        override fun onTick(millisUntilFinished: Long) {
            secondsRemaining = millisUntilFinished / 1000
            showNotification()
        }
    }.start()
}

private fun onTimerFinished(ring: Boolean = true) {
    if (ring) {
        //irrelevant code, ring and vibrate if timer is finished
    }
    showNotification(true)
}

@TargetApi(26)
private fun NotificationManager.createNotificationChannel(
    channelID: String,
    channelName: String,
    playSound: Boolean
) {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        val channelImportance = if (playSound) NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT
        else NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_LOW
        val nChannel = NotificationChannel(channelID, channelName, channelImportance)
        nChannel.enableLights(true)
        nChannel.lightColor = Color.BLUE
        this.createNotificationChannel(nChannel)
    }
}

private fun <T> getPendingIntentWithStack(
    context: Context,
    javaClass: Class<T>
): PendingIntent {
    val resultIntent = Intent(context, javaClass)
    resultIntent.flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP or Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP

    val stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(context)
    stackBuilder.addParentStack(javaClass)
    stackBuilder.addNextIntent(resultIntent)

    return if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(0, PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE)
    } else {
        stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(0, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT)
    }
}
}
```

Thank you so much in advance, I tried fixing the bug for weeks now but it's hard to fix it, because everything works for myself.

Comment: You have five seconds until system throws that exception did you try to call `startForeground` immediatelly inside onCreate?

Comment: Thanks for the quick comment! I haven't yet, but would that make a difference? I immediatly call `showNotification()` in `onCreate()`. In `showNotification()` are not some complex calculations, it should definitly not take 5 sec to get to `startForeground()` in the end... Or would you say it is worth a try? The problem with testing is, that I have to release an update in Playstore and wait for some days because the error doesn't occur for myself.

Comment: I've bad experience with services so I would definately try that. Its bad that you can't reproduce this on you local device and have to push an update but it is what it is, good luck

Comment: Okay thanks, I'll try... How can I call `startForeground()` in onCreate without having built the notification yet?

Comment: So I created a dummy "loading-notification" with the same ID now, that gets updated in the `showNotification()` method to show the real content. I'll try that for the next few days.

Comment: You always need to provide a notification. Personally in my projects I built an initial notification and then I just update it either from some static method or from inside `onStartCommand`

Comment: Yep, as I said, it was a notification with an icon and the text "loading". One Problem: I still got some crashes in the newest version I published yesterday with `startforeground()` in `oncreate()` - any further tips?

Comment: Today, I meet the same question， and finally, I found the `startForeground` error.
because it is compatible with Android12, I wrote a bug and created an error Notification.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So I've almost fixed the problem and no longer get hundreds of crashes every week, but only about one every two days.

Solution is this, when starting the foreground service: Just wait for the main looper in the main thread and then start it. It is much more common, that the 5s until the service needs to be started are enough now.

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
    Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post{
        MyContext.getContext().startForegroundService(Intent(this, NotificationUtil::class.java))
    }
} else {
            startService(Intent(this, NotificationUtil::class.java))
}
```

Comment: This method didn't work for me. Are there any innovations? A different method?

Comment: Unfortunately not. I don't get this crash that often anymore after my fix, however, there are some different solutions in other posts on stackoverflow for this problem - they didn't work for me but maybe they will for you :)

Comment: It stops for crash but it side effects by not starting the service at a longer time till Main looper doesn't came in role