# Android media3 startForground crash

Tags: android, audio, exoplayer, android-media3

I have a media player application. I'm using MediaSessionService. In onCreate() i create Exoplayer instance.

```
    mTrackSelector = DefaultTrackSelector(this)
    mTrackSelector.parameters = mTrackSelector.parameters
        .buildUpon()
        .setPreferredAudioLanguage("en")
        .setPreferredTextLanguage("en")
        .build()

    val mAudioAttr = AudioAttributes.Builder()
        .setUsage(C.USAGE_MEDIA)
        .setContentType(C.AUDIO_CONTENT_TYPE_SPEECH)
        .build()

    mPlayer = ExoPlayer.Builder(this)
        .setSeekBackIncrementMs(30000)
        .setSeekForwardIncrementMs(30000)
        .setTrackSelector(mTrackSelector)
        .setAudioAttributes(mAudioAttr, true)
        .setVideoScalingMode(C.VIDEO_SCALING_MODE_SCALE_TO_FIT)
        .build()
```

After that i'm creating MediaSession using ForwardingPlayer to adjust controls

```
        mMediaSession = MediaSession.Builder(this, forwardingPlayer)
            .setId(System.currentTimeMillis().toString().takeLast(5))
            .setCallback(librarySessionCallback).build()
```

As far as i test it's all good for my player to run and post a media3 control notification. Wihout using user permission for notification or use push notification. I test it on android 8-14.  Tested on android 13 in emulator

The problem is in production i receive throw Firebase Crashlitycs raports about :

```
     Fatal Exception: 
android.app.RemoteServiceException$ForegroundServiceDidNotStartInTimeException
Context.startForegroundService() did not then call Service.startForeground(): 
ServiceRecord{4e0c02b u0 xx.xxxxx.PlayerService}
```

on android 13

I did not implement any MediaSessionServiceListener and override onForegroundServiceStartNotAllowedException because in my tests on android 13 and above on phones and emulator did not crash. For test i implement those but i still have no crash or any log in

```
    override fun onForegroundServiceStartNotAllowedException() {
        Log.d("testCrash", "*) ------> CRASH!! CRASH!!")
    }
```

What i'm doing wrong? On my phones it did not crash
How can i reproduce the crash ? onForegroundServiceStartNotAllowedException is not called on any android 13-14 of my phones

in gradle i have   compileSdk 34 & targetSdk 34

I notice that YouTube premium does not ask for any notification permission and i can use audio in background on my android 13 and 14 phones

Thanks,

LE: i start my service using :

```
 val mSessionToken = SessionToken(nInterface.getActivity(), ComponentName(nInterface.getActivity(), PlayerService::class.java))
```

My AndroidManifest :

```
  <service android:name=".engine.notification.PlayerService"
        android:foregroundServiceType="mediaPlayback"
        android:stopWithTask="true"
        android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="androidx.media3.session.MediaSessionService"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </service>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE_MEDIA_PLAYBACK" />
```

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70880379/android-remoteserviceexeption-context-startforegroundservice-did-not-then-cal) help?

Comment: I can not reproduce the crash i receive in firebase reports. On all of my phones app works without crash.  The questions are : what i'm doing wrong or how can i reproduce the crash ?

Comment: in your PlayerService class onStart(if I am not mistaken) you should call this.startForeground()  and create a notification during 5 seconds after you started your service via context.startForegroundService(PlayerService::class)

Comment: i'm starting service using SessionToken(nInterface.getActivity(), ComponentName(nInterface.getActivity(), PlayerService::class.java)) and using inside my MediaSessionService MediaSession.Builder i receive automatically media3 notification player with controls.  I do not custom manage any notification. All my reported crashes are from samsung phones. I test it my app on samsung phones and dit not crash with  ForegroundServiceDidNotStartInTimeException